# PHP: Check whether an integer is in a certain interval or not

Tags: php, symfony, attributes, doctrine

I am currently working on an achievement system for a small online game. The achievement entity basically has 4 attributes:

- id
- earnedBy
- earnedOn
- progress

The last one is supposed to be a percentage, meaning a number between 0 and 100. In order to make sure that no numbers greater than 100 or smaller than 0 are saved in the database, my setter-method looks as followed (I am using Symfony2 / Doctrine ORM):

```
public function setProgress($progress)
    {
        $this->progress = max(min($progress, 100), 0);

        return $this;
    }
```

The important line here is `max(min($progress, 100), 0)`.

It works totally fine, I just wanted to ask, if there is another built-in function in PHP doing exactly that thing, and if what I am doing is okay (concerning good-developing style)

Comment: i dont think there's any such built-in function for what you need, AND what you currently are doing is perfectly fine..

Comment: Looks good. I'd probably break it into two lines instead of nesting it to make the max() min() function calls more readable.

Comment: @tereško, context matters. Given he is using the Symfony2 framework, there might be a more appropriate solution for his problem.

Comment: @Gerry, no, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider adding some constraints on your entity from [the validation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) of Symfony2.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Achievement
{
   /**
    * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=100)
    */
    protected progress;
}
```

The validator service is called automatically when for example validating forms, but you can even call it manually by getting the validator service, for example in your controller.

```
$achievement = new Achievement();
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($achievement);
```

Comment: You really should not use the Symfony's DI Container as a simple Service Locator. You might find [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) quite interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP 5.2 there are [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions with considerable set of [options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) available.

One of them lets you check for number being in a range:

```
$param = 10;

$result = filter_var( $param, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, [
    'options' => [
        'min_range' => 20, 
        'max_range' => 40
    ]
]);

var_dump( $result ); // will return FALSE for 10
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/kVwx7L

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Range`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Range.html) constraint:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range;

class Achievement
{
    /**
     * @Range(min=0, max=100)
     */
    private $progress;
}
```

[Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html) in Symfony is handled by a separate layer, so you should *not* do it in setters.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is *no*, there is no built-in function in PHP which "truncates" a number at lower and upper boundaries. 
And it's really ok to write `min(max(x, max_value), min_value)` - it is short and readable.